# Extract raw data from affyBatch object

Tags: r, extract, bioconductor

I have an affyBatch object with gene expression data.  The data is read in using
    dat <- ReadAffy()
with no options.  I then extract the 5600 genes that I am interested in using,
    dat <- RemoveProbes(listOutProbeSets, cdfpackagename, probepackagename)

I then normalise the expression data using
    dat.rma <- rma(dat)

Now I want to the export the raw data AND the rma-normalised data to .csv files.  Inspecting the data I find that exprs(dat) has dimensions 226576 by 30 and dat.rma has dimensions 5600 by 30.  How do I extract the 5600 by 30 matrix of the RAW expression values?  I don't know where the 226576 rows in the raw data have come from!

I'm a bit of a beginner with bioconductor data structures!  Sorry for not providing runnable example code - not sure how I would do that in this case.

Comment: No doubt there are experts who work with this sort of data on this forum, but you might have more luck at the http://biostar.stackexchange.com, which is "stackoverflow" for bioinformatics, computational genomics and systems biology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During transformation from raw to rma-normalised data, you have, among other things, combined/summarised low level probe intensity values into probe sets values (that map to genes). This explains why you have more features in a raw `AffyBatch` object than in a `ExpressionSet` instance (created by the `rma` function). Also, depending on the chip you have, there are several perfect match (PM) and miss match (MM) probes per probeset, which boosts the number of probes per probeset. The mapping probe -> probeset is defined in the chip definition file and handled automatically.

A few additional thoughts though. Removing probes before doing normalisation might not be a good thing to do. One assumption when performing normalisation is that most of you 'genes' do not change, so keeping only '*those of interest*' might break this, depending what '*those of interest*' means of course. You can always do your filtering on the `ExpressionSet`, after normalisation:

```
> library(affydata)
> data(Dilution) ## gets some test data
> eset <- rma(Dilution) ## rma normalisation
> featureNames(eset)[1:10] ## gets some probesets of interest
> ps
 [1] "100_g_at"  "1000_at"   "1001_at"   "1002_f_at" "1003_s_at" "1004_at"  
 [7] "1005_at"   "1006_at"   "1007_s_at" "1008_f_at"
> dim(eset) ## full dataset
Features  Samples 
   12625        4 
> dim(eset[ps,]) ## only 10 first probesets of interest
Features  Samples 
      10        4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are extracting a sample of the data in the eset matrix which contains the rma-normalised expression data.  Is there no way to extract it pre-normalisation?  It may be that my question doesn't really "make sense" - I'm just research for a request from a colleague.
I have done the normalisation after gene-selection since in our case we are certain that we don't want to include the effect of the genes "not of interest".  But I will certainly be aware of that in the future!
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There might be other ways, but using the `RemoveProves` code to extract certain probes of interest before doing any processing is fine. I have use the same strategy it in the past.